# Adding data in a Colum, as long as a string matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working with two datasets and I'm not sure how to do a join of data in python.

Below are my CSV's in a google spreadsheet

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OI0kv1jOvkXMelIXzKLC4wO7Eh5nIeQ2b2mk64glsZ8/edit#gid=0

Effectively what I want to do is, I want to apply my MAP ID's from data set 1 to data set 2 and use the serial number as the main way to join them. Right now all I'm doing is hardcoding a string when I'm creating a the CSV and that's not fit for purpose.

```
def make_csv():
    df['Map'] = 'SMA'
```

Should I be running these data set 1 and 2 into a DF and then joining that way using something like a if statement?

I've included the test set so everyone can have a look at what I'm working with.

Comment: Please, don't use external links. Paste the data inside your question (in text form, with correct formatting).

Comment: you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
or https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html 
there are a lot of explanation on how to do this on the web and here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1[['serial_number', 'MAP ID']], df2, how='inner',
             left_on='serial_number', right_on='New Serial Number') \
      .drop(columns='serial_number')


  MAP ID New Serial Number  ...  New Meter Manufacturer  New YOM
0    SMP    G4F01323562000  ...                     FLN     2020
1   SMAP    G4F90747271900  ...                     FLN     2020
2    SMP    G4F90747281900  ...                     FLN     2020
3   SMAP    G4F90747291900  ...                     FLN     2021

[4 rows x 7 columns]
```

Use the `how` parameter of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to adjust the type of merge to be performed.